# Hash Set is not returning unique values

Tags: c#, sql, hashset

I want  only the unique values from hashset in my SQL query.

Code for storing Unique values:

```
var id = new HashSet<String>();
id.Add("A");
id.Add("A");
id.Add("B");
```

Now I want to pass the unique values into a SQL query and find the records matching the unique ID.

I am doing it the following way.

```
DataTable da2 = new DataTable();
foreach(var grp in id)
{
    string uid = grp;
    string s3 = "Select id, fname, lname, dob from ifile where id= @uid";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(s3, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", uid);
    con.Open();
    da2.Load(cmd1.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();
}
Gridview1.DataSource=da2;
```

When I execute this query it is returning the duplicate records too.

Also, previously I was just displaying the unique ID's and for it I was using the following method and it was working fine.

```
GridView1.DataSource = id.Select(id1 => new { id1 }).ToList();
```

Since I want to display more attributes I cannot use the above method.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: So why have you stored duplicate ID's at all in database?

Comment: Your code sample do not seem to be at all related? It looks as if you are storing duplicate entries in the database. I'm not understanding the problem?

Comment: you first 4 lines of code won't compile if you have `Hashset` change it to HashSet<string> I will post code that will work as well as automatically stop duplicates from being added

Comment: @TimSchmelter By Database you mean Hashset?

Comment: @John No. You stated that the query returns duplicates as well.

Comment: @JohnKraft Look I did not list my whole process but here is what I am doing. I am using Lucene to find me ID's that matched a particular query. So for example if the user inputs John I use Lucene to find me the records matching John, then I get the ID of that query and store it in the hashset. Because I dont have all the attributes in my Lucene Index I am using SQL query to get the required attributes from another database by matching the ID. The problem is I am not able to retrieve the unique values for some reason, duplicates recs are being displayed

Comment: @BrokenGlass I changed the code before the OP updated his question.. looks like you arrived late to the party

Comment: `if this sql statement returns duplicates "Select id, fname, lname, dob ` then you have duplicate ID's in your database if you want to eliminate returning Duplicate then add `Distinct` in that Select Statement

Comment: @Habib Why not? I am storing the values in Hashset. Hashset is supposed to store only unique values right?

Comment: @John Are there actually multiple records with the same IDs in the DB?  Or are you saying that the code is pulling back the same record more than once?

Comment: @DaxFohl Yes, there are multiple records with the same ID in the database.

Comment: @DaxFohl oops. I think I got what you are trying to say. but what will be the SQL query to return distinct values with other attributes?

Comment: @john So that's the problem.  If there are multiple records with the same ID, then which one would you want to display?

Comment: @DaxFohl I just want to display the first one I guess.

Comment: @All I feel stupid for asking this question. Sorry guys. I was not paying my attention to the database part. Is it okay if I delete this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want to modify your SQL statement to `SELECT DISTINCT` or `SELECT TOP 1` if there are multiple records with the same ID.  That said, it's troublesome to have multiple records with the same ID in the database.  Better to name that column something else.